# i want to store toggle state in cookie and also want to close previous list when next list is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/deepansh/BHCZ4/2/ this is a fiddle.

I want to save toggle state in cookie so that after page reload I get the same state, and I want to close previously-open list after clicking for opening new list.

I want to do in in minimum lines.

HTML

```
<ul class="nav sidebar-nav" id="am_menu">
    <li><a href="#"> <span>User</span></a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Add User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">List User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">User Profile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#"> <span>User</span></a> 
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Add User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">List User</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">User Profile</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    width: 200px;
}
img {
    width: 14px;
}
li ul {
    display: none;
}
li ul {
    padding-left: 4em;
    list-style:none;
}
li ul li {
    line-height:35px;
}
li ul li ul {
    padding-left: .5em;
}
```

JS

```
$(function () {
    $('li').filter(function (i) {
        return $('ul', this).length >= 1;
    }).each(function (i) {
        $(this).children("a")
            .click(function (e) {
            var $ul = $(this).next("ul");
            if ($ul.is(":visible")) {
                $ul.find("ul").toggle("slow()");
                $ul.toggle("slow()");
            } else {
                $ul.toggle("slow()");
            };
        })

    });
});
```

Comment: I can't find a question in your text. Where is the problem?

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MCy2B/1/

Comment: i also want to store toggle state in cookie.. so that on page refresh i got the same state of submenu.

Comment: "*I want to do in in minimum lines.*" - why? What does the number of lines have to do with anything, and why is it a requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd personally take the approach (using, as in Arun's answer, the [$.cookie plugin](http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.0/jquery.cookie.js)):

```
$(function () {
    var toShow = $.cookie('lastShownIndex'),
        topLevel = $('#am_menu').find('> li');

    topLevel.click(function(){
        $(this).children('ul').slideToggle().end().siblings().children('ul').slideUp();
        $.cookie('lastShownIndex', $(this).index());
    }).eq(toShow).find('ul').show();
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/BHCZ4/3/).

References:

- [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/).
- [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/).
- [`end()`](http://api.jquery.com/end/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/).

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin is used

```
$(function () {
    $('#am_menu li:has(ul) > a').click(function (e) {
        var $ul = $(this).next("ul");
        $ul.toggle("slow");
        $('#am_menu li ul').not($ul).slideUp();
        $.cookie('curr.menu', $(this).parent().index())
    });

    var cindex = $.cookie('curr.menu');
    if (cindex != undefined) {
        $('#am_menu li:has(ul)').eq(cindex).children('a').click()
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/MCy2B/)

Comment: working on fiddle but not wid my code.. m still tring.. but thanx for helping me

Comment: @Deepansh did you include the plugin

Comment: yah ofcource.. listing expand collapse eorking well but cookie problem.. after refresh submenu again collapsed